# How to load an image to a ImageCell on Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to load icons into a ImageCell inside a ListView, but when I build my project the icon doesn't appear on the ImageCell.

Here's my project structure:

[image]

Here's my XAML page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyNotes.StartPage">

  <MasterDetailPage.Master Title="Menu">
    <ContentPage Title="Menu">
      <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ListView x:Name="listViewMaster" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ImageCell Text="{Binding Title}" ImageSource="{Binding IconSource}" />
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
      </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>

  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <ContentPage>

    </ContentPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>

</MasterDetailPage>
```

And here's the code behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyNotes
{
    public partial class StartPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        public StartPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();

            List<MasterPageItem> masterPageItems = new List<MasterPageItem>()
            {
                new MasterPageItem()
                {
                    Title = "Contacts",
                    IconSource = ImageSource.FromFile(@"c:\Projetos\MyNotes\MyNotes\MyNotes\Resources\image\contacts.png"),
                    TargetType = typeof(ContactPage)
                },
                new MasterPageItem()
                {
                    Title = "Todo List",
                    IconSource = ImageSource.FromFile(@"Resources\image\todo.png"),
                    TargetType = typeof(TodoListPage)
                },
                new MasterPageItem()
                {
                    Title = "Reminder",
                    IconSource = ImageSource.FromResource("Resources.image.reminder.png"),
                    TargetType = typeof(ContactPage)
                }
            };

            listViewMaster.ItemsSource = masterPageItems;
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The images go into your "native" projects:

- Xamarin.iOS = `BundledResource` Build Type
- Xamarin.Android = `AndroidResource` Build Type

---

```
IconSource = ImageSource.FromFile("SanFran.jpg")
```

or using the implicit conversion:

```
IconSource = "SanFran.jpg";
```

---

[image]

[Working with Images](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/)

Comment: Thank you. Once I moved the images to the correct folder inside the native project and set the correct Build Action it worked just fine.

Comment: I'm seeing something similar with ImageCell's where I have tried all variants that I can imagine and it is not appearing. Perhaps I need to set something else also.... Any ideas?

Comment: @TheSenator I would suggest you post a new question with the relevant code, image setup to understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Have you marked the images that you added to the project as embedded reousrces?

[embedded resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQufv.png)

Comment: Than I think you need to add the images as ImageSource.FromResource and not ImageSource.FromFile.

Comment: @AviK. FYI: Embedding them into the assembly and using `FromResource` is an option that will work, but it is not recommended in terms of performance & resource consumption. The best practice way is to use the native `BundledResource` or `AndroidResource` build types.

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks. I've created by question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40771645/how-do-i-display-an-image-in-a-xamarin-forms-imagecell-from-an-image-source