# EmbeddedImage in Xamarin Forms: how to bind it in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I am trying to follow the Xamarin documentation about Embedded Images:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Embedded_Images

This is the code snippet that I use in my portable application:

```
var embeddedImage = new Image { Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit };
embeddedImage.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("<MyNamespace>.<MyFolder>.imageFileName.jpg");

listItem.EmbeddedImage = embeddedImage;
```

Now I am trying to bind it in XAML, as part of a `ListView` (**note:** the `<Image Source="{Binding EmbeddedImage}" />` part is probably wrong) :

```
<ListView  x:Name="listView">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee"
        Orientation="Vertical">
          <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding EmbeddedImage}" /> // This is most likely wrong since it doesn't work       
          </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I've tested this with `<Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" />` and it works, so the rest of the code seems to be working as it should.

---

**Edit:**

Someone suggested this post as a solution:

[How to load an image to a ImageCell on Xamarin.Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489748/how-to-load-an-image-to-a-imagecell-on-xamarin-forms)

But the accepted answer there was:

> The images go into your "native" projects

...but actually the Xamarin documentation says that it can be done inside the portable project (so you wouldn't need to copy the same images/icons through all the "native" projects).

I know that putting them in every subproject would probably work, but that's not the point of my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load an image to a ImageCell on Xamarin.Forms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489748/how-to-load-an-image-to-a-imagecell-on-xamarin-forms)

Comment: @SushiHangover Your answer in the possible duplicate post was `The images go into your "native" projects`. But it looks like putting them in the portable project is possible, since it is detailed in the documentation: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Embedded_Images . Also, it looks like I'm not the only one feeling frustrated about this issue: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20585/how-to-load-embedded-image-resource-in-pcl-assembly

Comment: Using that method requires that you use a build type of `EmbeddedResource` and that is within your `Xamarin.Form` project/assembly. In terms of performance and resource consumption I would recommend using native bundling vs. assembly embedding... (This was also reviewed during Jason Smith's Evolve talk..)

Comment: It should be binded to an ImageSource not image

Answer (score 0):

You can access the resource directly in xaml by using `pack://application` uri.

```
<ListView  x:Name="listView">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee"
        Orientation="Vertical">
          <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/{AssemblyName};component/Images/MyImage.png" />     
          </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I don't seem to be able to make it work. I've placed my `test.png` in the root of the project, marked as "Embedded Resource". Then I use `<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/xamarin_test;/test.png" />` and the application simply shows nothing.

Comment: You need to add `;component` since it is the root of your project. Every next string between '\' represents a nested folder. And also can you make a snippet of how your project structure looks like?

Comment: I tested with `;component` as well and it didn't work. Here's the project structure: http://i.imgur.com/8f6Sai6.png?1

Comment: try with this: `pack://application:,,,/xamarin-test;component/test.png And make sure that the build action of `test.png` is set to either `Resource` or `Embedded Resource`

Comment: I agree that xamarin-test was a poor choice for the project name (I was not aware that the hyphen was changed to underscore). But I've tested that and it doesn't work either => http://imgur.com/lFSifVN

Comment: okay, this is now weird, can you change the build action to Resource and just reference the picture like this and see if it works?
`<Image Source="test.png" />`

Comment: I've created a new test project with a different name, and the result is the same... the image is not shown (no exceptions either, of course) => http://i.imgur.com/WB85r1g.png

Comment: "change the build action to Resource" => it doesn't seem to be one of the options (see http://i.imgur.com/SZV2nkq.png )

Comment: Just in case: the blank project was created like so => `New Project -> Visual C# -> Cross-Platform -> Blank App (Xamarin.Forms Portable)`.

Answer (score 0):

I've combed my hair out over this, and the problem is that Microsoft doesn't tell you the whole story in the Images docs. You have to go over to the Files docs to understand why it won't work.

Yes, you can use embedded resources in the shared project directory, but apparently under only one of two conditions:

1. You have to use a Markup Extension and then directly specify the resource path *in Xaml,* a la: `<Image Source="{local:ImageResource ProjectName.Images.flower.jpg"/>`
2. You write compiler directives in the code-behind that customize the beginning of the ResourceID per-platform.

**Option 1** requires hard-coding the path, so you can't use a dynamically-assigned image, and **Option 2** wrecks the whole point of trying to write cross-platform code.

---

**WAY HUGE EDIT: May be solved**

This post on the Xamarin forums made a huge difference for me: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17953/helpful-shared-project-image-information

*note:* the first post basically gives you all the code you need, but a little bit down in the thread there's some advice about project configurations that may be necessary for it to work correctly.

It basically introduces some custom code that programmatically derives the resource ID during runtime, so it's cross-platform code that customizes itself to whatever platform is currently running it. Working beautifully for me! Here's the version of the suggested approach that I'm using:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System;

namespace Helpers
{
    public class EmbeddedSourceror
    {
        public static Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource SourceFor(string pclFilePathInResourceFormat)
        {
            var resources = typeof(EmbeddedSourceror).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
            var resourceName = resources.Single(r => r.EndsWith(pclFilePathInResourceFormat, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            Debug.WriteLine("EmbeddedSourceror: resourceName string is " + resourceName);

            return Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource.FromResource(resourceName);
        }
    }
}
```

This lets you write the Xaml code in a totally normal way, such as:

```
<Image
            x:Name         ="backingImage"
            Aspect         ="AspectFill" />
```

And in the code-behind all you have to do is:

```
    backingImage.Source = EmbeddedSourceror.SourceFor("flower.jpg");
```